# How to enforce users to only upload files to certain nodes for particular files in Firebase.

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm trying out firebase storage, looking at that authorised users can upload files from a web client, I'm wondering what prevents users from changing paths by tweaking the javascript.

**Consider the following**

I want to organise user files as follows.

```
root : {
     users :
            uid1 : images {}
                 : audio {}
    -users:
            uid2 : images {}
                 : audio {} 
    -users:
          : uid3 : images {}
                 : audio {} 
     }
```

Then upload an image to /userid/images/

```
        var storage     = firebase.storage();
        var storageRef  = storage.ref();
        var imagesRef   = storageRef.child(uid_g).child('images').child(path);
```

**Problem :**

What prevents the user from changing the **child('images')** to **child('audio')** ?

I just want to make sure that a path I set will not be changed on storage.

The rules on the server Im allowing users only to read and write their data.

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/&lt;your-firbase-storage-bucket&gt;/o {
    // Files look like: "user/&lt;UID&gt;/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using Security Rules to create further path restrictions:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firbase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /user/{userId} {
      match /images {
        // This will match only /user/{userId}/images
        allow read, write: if imageCondition();
      }
      match /audio {
        // If you don't want the user to change to audio, you can either say if false or just don't include this path
        allow read, write: if audioCondition();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, which UserId is being checked against on the server? On javascript there's "firebase.auth().currentUser.u" and "firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)" where "user.uid" gives another and they are not the same.

Comment: Those shouldn't be different unless you've just changed authentication state (upgraded an anonymous account, logged in/out, etc.). If you call `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` inside the `onAuthStateChanged`, I would expect that to match `user.uid`, is that not happening?

Comment: No they are different, just tried it on a different user. "firebase.auth().currentUser.u" and "firebase.auth().currentUser.uid" are also different.

Comment: Do you mean `firebase.auth().currentUser.u` or `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` (you've typed it twice as `u`, so I'm not sure).